# Sumif Function involving dates and text

Tags: excel

I have a three columns which contain a range of dates, ie 6/15/2013, corresponding items ie. gravel, asphalt etc and corresponding tonnages. I need to be able to sum all of the tonnages of asphalt per month.

I have tried several sumif statements but they are all coming back with no value. Everything was going fine until I tried to add the sorting by month "if" statement.

Any help is appreciated.

Sample Data below

```
Column A | Column B | Column C 
6/23/2013| Asphalt  |    12 
7/14/2013| Asphalt  |    14 
6/15/2013| Gravel   |    15 
8/15/2013| Gravel   |    18 
6/3/2013 | Asphalt  |    14
```

thanks

Comment: Could you submit some sample data to give us something to chew on?

Comment: I would suggest creating a column containing the month (it uses `=MONTH()` on the date column) then run PivotTable on the data range. I believe it would be more maintainable than a formula/many formulae.

Comment: Column A   Column B  Column C
6/23/2013  Asphalt   12 
7/14/2013  Asphalt   14  
6/15/2013  Gravel   15  
8/15/2013  Gravel   18 
6/3/2013  Asphalt   14

I want the function to be able to tell me how many tones of Asphalt  we placed in June which should give an answer of  28 but right now I’m getting  “No Value”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 2007 or later try using `SUMIFS`, e.g. in F2

`=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"Asphalt",A:A,">="&E2,A:A,"<"&EOMONTH(E2,0)+1)`

where column A contains dates, B items and C tonnages....and E2 should contain the **1st** of the month for which you want to sum. You can add more more dates in E3 down and then copy that formula down